# Bubblewrap build no encuentra el twa-manifest.json

Tags: pwa

Estoy intentando generar una app TWA a partir de un desarrollo Angular que ya funciona como PWA.
Estoy desarrollando con Visual Studio Code.
Siguiendo las propias indicaciones de **bubblewrap** ([github/GoogleChromeLabs/](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/tree/master/packages/cli):

- verifique que tengo instalada una versión de JDK 8,
- descargué Android CLI y ejecuté `npm i -g @bubblewrap/cli`
- omití el siguiente paso: `bubblewrap init --manifest https://my-twa.com/manifest.json` porque aún no tengo publicada la app
- cuando ejecuto `bubblewrap build` el sdkmanager.bat instala las tools de Android, pero finaliza arrojando este error:

> cli ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Backup\cNestor\_All Techs\Mobile\GitLAB projects\poc-kccsss-scheduler\twa-manifest.json'

Mi pregunta es si este procedimiento es correcto hacerlo desde VS Code o debería instalar Android Studio

Otra duda es respecto al punto 3 que omití (el init), debo hacerlo sí o sí antes de intentar el build? Supongo que este paso debería generar el **twa-manfest.json**, pero ignoro que debería informarle como URL para el manifiesto `https://my-twa.com/manifest.json`

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio no es necesario para usar bubblewrap, pero correr init sí es absolutamente necesario, el Android wrapper se crea a partir del manifest.json si no le pases el manifest bubblewrap no ha creado el wrapper y por lo tanto no se puede correr el build.